# How can I make the *ngfor work in a modal?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Im using he *ngfor but the modal its not working for some reason

```
<table *ngFor="let wt of wtl">
                <tr>
                    <td *>
                        <mat-form-field style=" width: 600px;">
                            <textarea rows="8" cols="360" matInput [(ngModel)]="wt.description" name="comment"
                                type="text" id="description" placeholder="Comentarios de Cierre"
                                autocomplete="off"></textarea>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </tr>

               
            </table>
```

[thats the way the modal is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cymjw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to tell what functionality you want. But try putting the ngFor in the tr tag. This should populate the rows of your table with your forms.

```
  <tr *ngFor="let wt of wtl">
```

Also this tag

```
<td *>
```

I am not familiar with putting an * by itself next to a tag, and it gives me an error, so you may want to remove the * if it was not intentional.

```
<td>
```